# A "pun" that I can't understand, at all

Tags: puns

In the book The Quantum Universe: Everything That Can Happen Does Happen by Brian Cox and Jeff Forshaw, on page 104 there seems to be a pun of authors:

> Generally speaking, *frequency* is the fundamental quantity that describes standing waves, and this sentence is probably a pun.

No matter how many times I read this I can't understand what the actual "pun" is. Is it because these particular waves are called "standing," whereas the word "frequency" implies something happening?

Comment: It's possibly because standing waves have a _fundamental frequency_.

Comment: Thank you. This makes perfect sense. I'm going to read the chapter again with this in mind.

Comment: I guess that use of *fundamental* is borderline pun-esque, but if that's all there is to the pun it it was barely worth pointing out. Maybe I'm just not on the same wavelength as the authors.

Comment: @nnnnnn The did say it was _probably_ a pun, but when one of them was in a pop band called D:ream what can you expect. Things can only get better. That's probably a pun.